# Eclipse shortcut to find function name

Tags: java, eclipse

I have certain methods/functions in a class which are fairly very large, 3-4k lines. (Poor design, dont ask) which makes navigation very difficult.

Is there a certain shortcut in eclipse, such that, if i am at a certain line of code, using the shortcut will take me directly to the beginning of the function or atleast give me the name of the function.

Comment: clrt +o then it will open the list of all members in the class there you can search name by typing in search bar

Comment: use these links http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use *Outline* view. If you have your cursor within a method, the appropriate method will be selected in the view and *double-clicking* on the selected method will take you to the top of the method.

*Screenshot coming up.*

**Edit:**[image]

Answer (score 19):

Ctrl+o might be what you are looking for.

It will list out all the methods under the class file.

You just take a look at all other shorcut keys available here http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> shows you all member variable or method available in class

Comment: @TheUnusual he's also asking for the same

Comment: doesn't it shows you `member variable`? Eclipse let me show all the method and member variable

Comment: @TheUnusual : Some problem with your Eclipse. Even mine shows.

Comment: @TheUnusual Have you defined any class variables? I think if it shows methods then then should show member variables too...

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>  which gives a list of methods in the popup.

That gives Outline of current source

It lists all the methods in the `File.`

[All shortcuts](http://www.allapplabs.com/eclipse/eclipse_shortcuts.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `Bread crumb` available in Eclipse. You can enable it using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

You can have quick access to packages, classes and methods.

Check here http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + (Arrow Up) takes you to the beginning of a function. (At least in my configuration).